# Using sentry to capture network traffic and show on my custom page

Tags: javascript, sentry

I want to use sentry.io to capture logs and network traffic from a webpage. I can see the details on sentry dashboard. But is there any way to show this info in my own custom page web page, something like
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use a service worker to intercept all network requests - and then log/report them as you wish.

Comment: intercepting console or network traffic is not an issue, but presenting it like above is quite an effort! So I was looking for a 3rd party lib to make it readable

Comment: I am not aware of such feature on Sentry. Perhaps [tracing](https://blog.sentry.io/2022/04/13/how-to-surface-relevant-performance-data/) is what you're looking for? Or maybe some [profiling](https://blog.sentry.io/2022/03/01/continuous-performance-improvement-of-http-api/) ?

Comment: o yes, its tracing!!!